# Pandas read_csv from url

Tags: python, csv, pandas, request

I'm trying to read a csv-file from given URL, using Python 3.x:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

url = "https://github.com/cs109/2014_data/blob/master/countries.csv"
s = requests.get(url).content
c = pd.read_csv(s)
```

I have the following error

> "Expected file path name or file-like object, got <class 'bytes'> type"

How can I fix this? I'm using Python 3.4

Comment: You would need something like `c=pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s.decode("utf-8")))` but you are getting html back not a csv file so it is not going to work

Comment: I'm fairly certain the URL you want is `"https://raw.github.com/cs109/2014_data/blob/master/countries.csv"`.

Comment: @venom, chose more popular answer as the right one

Comment: Sicne the issue was with `pandas.read_csv()` not Python, you should have stated the pandas version too, but given [Python 3.4 was released in 2014](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-340/), so you were likely running [pandas 0.12 .. 0.15](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/releases?after=v0.15.2)

Comment: Since Pandas 1.2 for basic HTTP authentication: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68307497/940098

Answer (score 260, accepted):

UPDATE: From pandas `0.19.2` you can now just [**pass `read_csv()` the url directly**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41880513/2071807), although that will fail if it requires authentication.

---

For **older pandas versions**, or **if you need authentication**, or for any other HTTP-fault-tolerant reason:

**Use `pandas.read_csv` with a file-like object as the first argument.**

- If you want to read the csv from a string, you can use [`io.StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO).
- For the URL `https://github.com/cs109/2014_data/blob/master/countries.csv`, you get **`html`** response, not **raw** csv; you should use the url given by the `Raw` link in the github page for getting raw csv response , which is `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cs109/2014_data/master/countries.csv`

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import io
import requests
url="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cs109/2014_data/master/countries.csv"
s=requests.get(url).content
c=pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s.decode('utf-8')))
```

Notes:

in Python 2.x, the string-buffer object was [`StringIO.StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html#StringIO.StringIO)

Comment: What if the response is large and I want to stream it instead of consuming memory for the encoded content, decoded content and the StringIO object?

Comment: In the latest version of pandas you can give the url directly i.e. `c=pd.read_csv(url)`

Comment: Curiously I have a newer version of `pandas` (0.23.4), but I could not give url directly. This answer helped me get that working.

Comment: "Update
From pandas 0.19.2 you can now just pass the url directly." Unless you can't because you need to pass authentication arguments, in which case the original example is much needed.

Comment: This solution still valuable if you need a better error handling using HTTP codes that may be returned by request object (ex: 500 -> retry may be needed, 404 -> no retry)

Comment: This seems to put all columns in one column for this url: https://www.ebi.ac.uk/Tools/services/rest/clustalo/result/clustalo-I20201101-053806-0987-43608676-p1m/pim

Comment: This allows you to specify a timeout in requests.get, which one should always set in production code

Answer (score 353):

In the latest version of pandas (`0.19.2`) you can directly pass the url

```
import pandas as pd

url="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cs109/2014_data/master/countries.csv"
c=pd.read_csv(url)
```

Comment: it seems that using this directly instead of requests directly does not use [requests-cache](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests-cache) even if used

Comment: That code returns `urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:777)>` because of the https protocol which urllib cannot handle.

Comment: For those using Python 2, you will have to use Python 2.7.10+.

Comment: There seems to be some issue reading csv from a URL. I read the file once from a local storage and once from URL, I kept getting errors from URL. I then enabled error_bad_lines=False and more than 99% of data was ignored. The URL is [link](https://www.kaggle.com/c/digit-recognizer/download/train.csv). Once I read the file, the shape of the dataset was found to be (88,1), which is completely wrong

Comment: It seems not work well, I got an
 issue of urlopen error :`<urlopen error [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed>`

Comment: I installed certificate following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52805115/certificate-verify-failed-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate, then pd.read_csv(url) works for me.

Answer (score 20):

As I commented you need to use a StringIO  object and decode i.e `c=pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s.decode("utf-8")))` if using requests, you need to decode as .content returns *bytes* if you used .text you would just need to pass s as is `s = requests.get(url).text` c = `pd.read_csv(StringIO(s))`.

A simpler approach is to pass the correct url of the *raw* data directly to `read_csv`, you **don't** have to pass a file like object, you can pass a url so you don't need requests at all:

```
c = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cs109/2014_data/master/countries.csv")

print(c)
```

Output:

```
                              Country         Region
0                             Algeria         AFRICA
1                              Angola         AFRICA
2                               Benin         AFRICA
3                            Botswana         AFRICA
4                             Burkina         AFRICA
5                             Burundi         AFRICA
6                            Cameroon         AFRICA
..................................
```

From the  [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

**filepath_or_buffer** :

> string or file handle / StringIO
>   The string could be a URL. Valid URL schemes include http, ftp, s3, and file. For file URLs, a host is expected. For instance, a local file could be file ://localhost/path/to/table.csv

Comment: You can feed the url directly to pandas read_csv! of course! that's a much simpler solution than the one I found! :D

Comment: @pabtorre, yep , an example of  why reading the docs is a good idea.

Comment: That works, in my case though ,I need to set  the param `sep` of  function `pd.read_csv`, such as : `pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), sep='\t')` . If I use the default setting `sep=None` , it'll raise an error`Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 6, saw 5`

Comment: Why do I still get just one column for this url? https://www.ebi.ac.uk/Tools/services/rest/clustalo/result/clustalo-I20201101-053806-0987-43608676-p1m/pim

Answer (score 11):

The problem you're having is that the output you get into the variable 's' is not a csv, but a html file. 
In order to get the raw csv, you have to modify the url to:

'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cs109/2014_data/master/countries.csv'

Your second problem is that read_csv expects a file name, we can solve this by using StringIO from io module. 
Third problem is that request.get(url).content delivers a byte stream, we can solve this using the request.get(url).text instead.

End result is this code:

```
from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd
import requests
url='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cs109/2014_data/master/countries.csv'
s=requests.get(url).text

c=pd.read_csv(StringIO(s))
```

output:

```
>>> c.head()
    Country  Region
0   Algeria  AFRICA
1    Angola  AFRICA
2     Benin  AFRICA
3  Botswana  AFRICA
4   Burkina  AFRICA
```

Answer (score 6):

```py
url = "https://github.com/cs109/2014_data/blob/master/countries.csv"
c = pd.read_csv(url, sep = "\t")
```

Comment: Please provide explanation how your solution works.

Comment: This may raise an url error ：`urlopen error [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed`

Answer (score 0):

> ## To Import Data through URL in pandas just apply the simple below code it works actually better.

```
import pandas as pd
train = pd.read_table("https://urlandfile.com/dataset.csv")
train.head()
```

> ## If you are having issues with a raw data then just put 'r' before URL

```
import pandas as pd
train = pd.read_table(r"https://urlandfile.com/dataset.csv")
train.head()
```