# Handling HTTP authentication when accesing remote urls via pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Pandas has a very convenient ability to read csv and other formats from urls.
However,when the data is protected by simple http authentication, Pandas is not capable to prompt the user for the the authentication details (userid, password). What is the best way to fix this limitation?

what I am currently doing is:

```
response = requests.get('http://my.data.url/metrics/crawler/counts', auth=HTTPBasicAuth('userid', 'password'), stream=True)
pd.read_csv(response.raw)
```

is there a better way?

Answer (score 14):

Since Pandas 1.2 [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) has `storage_options` argument:

> Extra options that make sense for a particular storage connection, e.g. host, port, username, password, etc. For HTTP(S) URLs the key-value pairs are forwarded to [`urllib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html) as header options. For other URLs (e.g. starting with “s3://”, and “gcs://”) the key-value pairs are forwarded to [`fsspec`](https://pypi.org/project/fsspec/). Please see [`fsspec`](https://pypi.org/project/fsspec/) and [`urllib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html) for more details.

`storage_options` controls HTTP headers, so one can construct Basic Auth `Authorization` header.

Run a HTTP server protected with `user:pass` Basic Auth serving a dummy CSV, `test.csv`.

```
docker run --rm -it -p 8000:8000 python:2-alpine sh -c \
  "echo -e 'key,value\nfoo,1\nbar,2' > test.csv \
   && pip install https://github.com/smarzola/extended_http_server/archive/e2006102.zip \
   && ext_http_server -a user:pass"
```

Python code to read it via `pandas.read_csv` would look like the following.

```
In [1]: import pandas

In [2]: try:
   ...:   pandas.read_csv('http://localhost:8000/test.csv')
   ...: except Exception as ex:
   ...:   print(ex)
HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized

In [3]: from base64 import b64encode
   ...: 
   ...: pandas.read_csv(
   ...:   'http://localhost:8000/test.csv',
   ...:   storage_options={'Authorization': b'Basic %s' % b64encode(b'user:pass')},
   ...: )
Out[3]: 
   key  value
0  foo      1
1  bar      2
```

Comment: can it also handle https?

Comment: @Arie Yes, it also handles https.

Answer (score 1):

you could do :

```
import requests
response = requests.get(url, auth=(username, password), verify=False)
```

(I might be too late ...)

Answer (score -1):

Not able to test, but it looks like basic access authentication can be encoded within the url. From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication):

> **URL encoding**
>
> A client may avoid a login prompt when accessing a basic access authentication by prepending username:password@ to the hostname in the url. For example, the following would access the page index.html at the web site www.example.com with the secure HTTPS protocol and provide the username Aladdin and the password OpenSesame credentials via basic authorization:
>   https://Aladdin:OpenSesame@www.example.com/index.html

Hope that helps!

Comment: This doesn't work. Pandas `read_csv` is not able to parse username, pwd if provided in URL itself. Here's the stack  `
    (self.host, self.port) = self._get_hostport(host, port)
  File "/Users/mohitranjan/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 792, in _get_hostport
    raise InvalidURL("nonnumeric port: '%s'" % host[i+1:])
httplib.InvalidURL: nonnumeric port: 'XXXXXX@YYY.com'`