# how to read csv from URL with Authentication in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I need to read a CSV file from URL. The URL is protected, so I need to pass the creds to access the file. There is a way by passing the username and password in the URL like below

```
URL = "https://username:password@mydomain.com/abc/xyz.csv"
df = pd.csv_reader(URL)
```

But the issue with the above pattern is password may contain the special characters like **@** so it will raise the exception.

The other way to do is using the request method to read the response and create the io string and pass it to the csv_reader.

Instead of using above two methods do we have other way to read the csv from URL?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Handling HTTP authentication when accesing remote urls via pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33039327/handling-http-authentication-when-accesing-remote-urls-via-pandas)

Comment: if it has `@` in password then you may have to convert to `%40` using  `urllib.parse.quote('@')`

Answer (score 0):

You should use the **requests** library to make a POST Html request with username and password as parameters. Then use the response as input for pandas :

```
import requests
  
URL = "https://example.com/abc/xyz.csv"
PARAMS = {'username':'my_username','password','my_password'}
response_csv = requests.get(url = URL, params = PARAMS)
df = pd.csv_reader(response_csv)
```