# How do I read a CSV directly into a pandas dataframe from a download link button?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, data-science

I'm trying to read the *Train File* directly into a pandas dataframe from the link address instead of downloading to my local computer then reading.

The website is:

https://datahack.analyticsvidhya.com/contest/practice-problem-loan-prediction-iii/download/#ProblemStatement

The link address when you right click the *Train File* at the bottom of the page is:

https://datahack.analyticsvidhya.com/contest/practice-problem-loan-prediction-iii/download/train-file

I tried:

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://datahack.analyticsvidhya.com/contest/practice-problem-loan-prediction-iii/download/train-file'
df = pd.read_csv(url)
```

The error is:

```
HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

I also tried using `requests` to download the CSV then reading it from my local computer, but I couldn't get that to work either.

Answer (score 0):

You need supply your login credentials to the website. With `requests` you pass them in as arguments, as follows:

```
response = requests.get(url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username, password))
```

Replace `username` and `password` with your username and password. It will authenticate the request and return a response 200 or else it will return error 403.

I have also found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33039327/handling-http-authentication-when-accesing-remote-urls-via-pandas), which may be helpful.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for the reply! I don't think that's the issue, because I can get a response 200 without the auth details using:

r = requests.get(url)

This retrieves the 'text/html' file, but I don't know how to extract the CSV from that. Whereas, if I just paste the URL into my browser it will automatically download the CSV.