# ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 11, saw 2

Tags: pandas

pd.read_csv("

Actual code looks like;

import pandas as pd

```
df = pd.read_csv('https://www.pythonanywhere.com/user/elksie5000/files/home/elksie5000/girls_long_count.csv')


Error: 
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 11, saw 2
    Name    Gender  Year    Measure Value   first_letter
55512   A'Idah  girl    2021    Count   0   A
55513   A'Isha  girl    2021    Count   3   A
55514   A'Ishah girl    2021    Count   4   A
55515   A'Niyah girl    2021    Count   0   A
55516   Aa'Idah girl    2021    Count   4   A
55517   Aa'Isha girl    2021    Count   0   A
55518   Aa'Ishah    girl    2021    Count   0   A
55519   Aabha   girl    2021    Count   3   A
55520   Aabida  girl    2021    Count   3   A
55521   Aabidah girl    2021    Count   0   A
55522   Aabish  girl    2021    Count   0   A
55523   Aadhira girl    2021    Count   13  A
55524   Aadhiraa    girl    2021    Count   3   A
55525   Aadhya  girl    2021    Count   35  A
```

[image]

Update: I tried

import pandas as pd

```
df = pd.read_csv('https://www.pythonanywhere.com/user/elksie5000/files/home/elksie5000/girls_long_rank.csv, on_bad_lines='skip')
```

The result was

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
0   <html lang="en" style="height: 100%">
1   <head>
2   <!-- Google tag (gtag.js) -->
3   <script async src="https://www.goo...
4   <script>
... ...
151 </div>
```

The raw CSV looks like this:

```
,Name,Gender,Year,Measure,Value,first_letter
55512,A'Idah,girl,2021,Count,0,A
55513,A'Isha,girl,2021,Count,3,A
55514,A'Ishah,girl,2021,Count,4,A
55515,A'Niyah,girl,2021,Count,0,A
55516,Aa'Idah,girl,2021,Count,4,A
55517,Aa'Isha,girl,2021,Count,0,A
55518,Aa'Ishah,girl,2021,Count,0,A
55519,Aabha,girl,2021,Count,3,A
55520,Aabida,girl,2021,Count,3,A
55521,Aabidah,girl,2021,Count,0,A
55522,Aabish,girl,2021,Count,0,A
55523,Aadhira,girl,2021,Count,13,A
55524,Aadhiraa,girl,2021,Count,3,A
55525,Aadhya,girl,2021,Count,35,A
55526,Aadila,girl,2021,Count,0,A
```

Comment: The default delimiter for `pd.read_csv` is a comma (","). The error `Expected 1 fields in line 11, saw 2` suggests that your file has 10 lines without a comma. So, each line is parsed as 1 field, until we hit line 11, which does have a comma (2 fields) and failure ensues. You can try `on_bad_lines='skip'` or `on_bad_lines='warn'` to ignore the line, which at least should give you some output (if there is no other corruption). You may then find that the file actually uses a different delimiter. E.g., a tab (`sep='\t'`) or a semi-colon (`sep=';'`).

Comment: I tried that. My results are confusing to say the least I'll the in an update.

Comment: So, it's a wholly different issue: you're not reading any csv, you're just reading the `html` from the site that you see when you try to access your url without being signed in. I.e., you'll need to add authentication somehow. Not sure if that is possible with `pd.read_csv`. Maybe have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33039327/18470692). Or maybe just download the file, and open it locally, if that's possible. Easiest for sure.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you're encountering is indicating that `pd.read_csv` is expecting a single field per line but encountered two fields in line 11, causing the parsing error.

The error occurs because the default delimiter for `pd.read_csv` is a comma (`,`), and your CSV file seems to use a different delimiter, possibly a tab (`\t`) or a semicolon (`;`).

You can resolve this issue by specifying the correct delimiter when reading the CSV file. If it's a tab delimiter, you can use the `sep` parameter like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Specify the tab delimiter
df = pd.read_csv('https://www.pythonanywhere.com/user/elksie5000/files/home/elksie5000/girls_long_count.csv', sep='\t')
```

Or, if it's a semicolon delimiter:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Specify the semicolon delimiter
df = pd.read_csv('https://www.pythonanywhere.com/user/elksie5000/files/home/elksie5000/girls_long_count.csv', sep=';')
```

This will correctly parse the CSV file with the specified delimiter, and you should not encounter the "ParserError" anymore.