# using pandas read_csv with a certificate

Tags: python, pandas, ssl-certificate

using this:

```
import pandas as pd
url = "https://example.net/update/last7days?format=csv"

se7enDays = pd.read_csv(url)
```

results in this:

`URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:646)>`

which i understand, but how can i load my cert AND pass the password to read_csv.

I had looked into using `urllib2` but didn't have any joy passing the file AND password in.

Ideally something like this is what i would like:

```
cafile = "/Users/toast/ossim_cert.pem"
ossim_cert_pw = "mypassword"
se7enDays = pd.read_csv(url, cafile=cafile:ossim_cert_pw)
```

Comment: Maybe use a file-like object wrapper of url reader that support certs. `pd.read_csv` doc says it takes `file_handle`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but was able to overcome it by using:

```
    x = requests.get(url=url, certs= certs).content 
    pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(x.decode('utf8')))
```

This link helped:  [Pandas read_csv from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32400867/pandas-read-csv-from-url)