# Convert text data from requests object to dataframe with pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe, python-requests

Using requests I am creating an object which is in .csv format. How can I then write that object to a DataFrame with pandas?

To get the requests object in text format:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
url = r'http://test.url' 
r = requests.get(url)
r.text  #this will return the data as text in csv format
```

I tried (doesn't work):

```
pd.read_csv(r.text)
pd.DataFrame.from_csv(r.text)
```

Comment: difficult to answer without seeing data.

Comment: May be you need save the response data to a file and check the file content. Then read the file to csv, check if this approach works. If not then there is something wrong in the data

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32400867/pandas-read-csv-from-url/32401251#32401251, no need for requests unless you are posting some data that allows you to access the content

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, I think you are wrong about requests, Its urllib2 or request. shhh, urllib2 has security flaws. which allow file access. So, requests is safer.

Comment: @Padraic, I omitted this part in my question but I needed to include a special header format in my request which is why I used requests instead of importing the url directly.  headers = {'user1': 'AppInterface'}

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Try this

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import io

urlData = requests.get(url).content
rawData = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(urlData.decode('utf-8')))
```

Comment: can we convert dataframe output to URL. display dataframe table output in the form of url : any one can access it  and see the dataframe data by opening that url ?

Answer (score 25):

I think you can use [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) with `url`:

```
pd.read_csv(url)
```

> **filepath_or_buffer** : str, pathlib.Path, py._path.local.LocalPath or any object with a read() method (such as a file handle or StringIO)
>
> The string could be a URL. Valid URL schemes include http, ftp, s3, and file. For file URLs, a host is expected. For instance, a local file could be file ://localhost/path/to/table.csv

```
import pandas as pd
import io
import requests

url = r'http://...' 
r = requests.get(url)  
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(r))
```

---

If it doesnt work, try update last line:

```
import pandas as pd
import io
import requests

url = r'http://...' 
r = requests.get(url)  
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(r.text))
```

Comment: With the second part works

Answer (score 5):

Using "read_csv with url" worked:

```
import requests, csv
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://arte.folha.uol.com.br/ciencia/2020/coronavirus/csv/mundo/dados-bra.csv'
corona_bra = pd.read_csv(url)
print(corona_bra.head())
```

Comment: I guess this will depend on the request URL, I need to pass parameters to get(), for example, requests.get(url,params=dict())

Comment: @gudé You can simply convert the parameters to a string using `'&'.join([f'{key}={value}' for key, value in params.items()])` and append to the rest of the URL.

Answer (score 2):

if the url has no authentication then you can directly use read_csv(url)

if you have authentication you can use request to get it un-pickel and print the csv and make sure the result is CSV and use panda.

You can directly use importing 
import csv