# Where in Python Pandas' source code are URLs handled by pd.read_csv?

Tags: python, pandas, http, url

The `pandas.read_csv` function is very flexible and recently has begun to support URL inputs as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32400867/pandas-read-csv-from-url)

```
df = pd.read_csv('http://www.somefile.csv')
```

I am attempting to find in the source code where this case is handled. Here is what I know so far:

1) `read_csv` is a fairly generic wrapper generated by `_make_parser_function` within `io/parsers.py`

2) The function produced by `_make_parser_function` delegates the reading of the data to a function `_read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)` that is defined elsewhere in `io/parsers.py`

3) This function `_read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)` creates a `TextFileReader` and returns the result of `TextFileReader.read()`. However, it appears that `TextFileReader` is responsible for, well, only text files. It provides functionality for handling various types of compression, but I see nothing checking for URL input.

4) On the other hand,`io/html.py` contains a function `_read(obj)` that clearly is to access a URL and return the result of an http query.

It seems to me that the simple solution to this problem is to check if the input string is a URL, and if so dispatch to the `html` module; however, I cannot find where this happens when tracing through `read_csv`. Could anybody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

You missed a step between 2 and 3.

2.5) `_read` [calls `get_filepath_or_buffer()`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.20.3/pandas/io/parsers.py#L391) where the url is recognized as such and read.

```
filepath_or_buffer, _, compression = get_filepath_or_buffer(
    filepath_or_buffer, encoding, compression)
```

[`get_filepath_or_buffer()` is defined in `pandas.io.common`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.20.3/pandas/io/common.py#L167):

```
def get_filepath_or_buffer(filepath_or_buffer, encoding=None,
                           compression=None):
    """
    If the filepath_or_buffer is a url, translate and return the buffer.
    Otherwise passthrough.
    Parameters
    ----------
    filepath_or_buffer : a url, filepath (str, py.path.local or pathlib.Path),
                         or buffer
    encoding : the encoding to use to decode py3 bytes, default is 'utf-8'
    Returns
    -------
    a filepath_or_buffer, the encoding, the compression
    """
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks -- the relevant line is literally the second line of code within the function you pointed out after the docstring `if _is_url(filepath_or_buffer):`