# how to download csv file to directory using python

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to download historical stock prices of AAPL from yahoo query but failed. I am very new to python and do not know which method to apply in auto extracting the designated link into my desired local directory.

> > pullData("AAPL") with result:
> >     AAPL
> >     https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/AAPL?period1=345398400&period2=1505577600&interval=1d&events=history&crumb=X44gAJPyoNu
> >     main loop HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized

```
import urllib2
import time
import csv
import requests
import pandas as pd

def pullData(stock):
    try:
        print stock
        url = 'https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/'+stock+'?period1=345398400&period2=1505577600&interval=1d&events=history&crumb=X44gAJPyoNu'
        print url

        response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        html = response.read()


    except Exception,e:
        print 'main loop',str(e)
```

Comment: Maybe this would help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32400867/pandas-read-csv-from-url

Answer (score 0):

You should updates the pandas datareader with this fix
https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/issues/315

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data as web

start = datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 1)
end = datetime.datetime(2016, 7, 1)
data - web.DataReader('AAPL', 'yahoo',start, end)
```