# How to set proxy for Pandas pd.read_csv

Tags: python, pandas, proxy, python-requests

I have a python script that loads a csv file from a server via https. I'm behind a corporate proxy, so I need to provide that info to the script.

Let

```
proxy_dict = {"https://user:password@10.10.1.1:8080"}
```

where all values are changed to be correct.

Using

```
print(requests.get(my_url, proxies=proxy_dict).text[:1000]
```

works as expected.

I want to use pandas.read_csv, which does not have a proxy argument.

How do I set the proxy for pandas? Either as a variable, or for the kernel, or system-wide, as long as only Python is affected.

Running Anaconda 3.6.3 x64 on Windows 7 x64.

Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

Maybe you can read the csv from a string, by using io.StringIO.

Please see the answer on: [Pandas read_csv from url](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32400969/7547749)

```
import io

s = requests.get(my_url, proxies=proxy_dict).text

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s))
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition, you need to do:
`proxy_dict = dict("https://user:password@10.10.1.1:8080")`

Comment: "ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required" this might work: proxy_dict = {"anything" : "https://user:password@10.10.1.1:8080"}

Comment: Yes, proxy_dict needs to be a dict.  I use the keys 'http' and 'https' in the proxy dict with the proxy you want to use).  This should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Found this question looking for a solution to read remote xls/xlsx file via proxy with pd.read_excel().

The solution that I found, was the following:

```
response = requests.get(url, proxies = proxy_dict)
filedata = BytesIO(response.content)   
df = pd.read_excel(filedata)
```