# Access online data using python

Tags: python

I am trying to access the federal reserve bank data at https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/FEDFUNDS
what is the code I can write to access this database and then put it in a dictionary? Or do I have to download the file first and save it on my computer?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to pull that data in would be to download and parse the CSV file listed under the "Download" button.

You can use the [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library to download the file, then use the native [CSV](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) library.

Answer (score 0):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/32400969/9214517 for how to do it.

Let's say you allow to keep the data in a pandas DataFrame (as the link above do), this is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import io
url = "https://fred.stlouisfed.org/graph/fredgraph.csv?bgcolor=%23e1e9f0&chart_type=line&drp=0&fo=open%20sans&graph_bgcolor=%23ffffff&height=450&mode=fred&recession_bars=on&txtcolor=%23444444&ts=12&tts=12&width=968&nt=0&thu=0&trc=0&show_legend=yes&show_axis_titles=yes&show_tooltip=yes&id=FEDFUNDS&scale=left&cosd=1954-07-01&coed=2018-10-01&line_color=%234572a7&link_values=false&line_style=solid&mark_type=none&mw=3&lw=2&ost=-99999&oet=99999&mma=0&fml=a&fq=Monthly&fam=avg&fgst=lin&fgsnd=2009-06-01&line_index=1&transformation=lin&vintage_date=2018-11-28&revision_date=2018-11-28&nd=1954-07-01"
s = requests.get(url).content.decode("utf-8")
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s)
```

Then your `df` will be:

```
           DATE  FEDFUNDS
0    1954-07-01      0.80
1    1954-08-01      1.22
2    1954-09-01      1.06
3    1954-10-01      0.85
4    1954-11-01      0.83
....
```

And if you insist on a `dict`, use this instead of the last line above to convert your CSV data `s`:

```
mydict = dict([line.split(",") for line in s.splitlines()])
```

The key is how to get the URL: Hit the download button on the page you quoted, and copy the link to CSV.