# python pandas.read_csv from url

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to read a csv file from url in python 3.7.1, but it keeps giving error. i found it doesn't even work for the iris dataset that was used in all tutorials. did search and couldn't figure out what's the issue. Anyone can help take a look? thanks!

## Load dataset

```
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/uiuc-cse/data-fa14/gh-pages/data/iris.csv'
names = ['sepal-length', 'sepal-width', 'petal-length', 'petal-width', 'class']
dataset = pd.read_csv(url, names=names)
```

Here is the error message:

```
SSLCertVerificationError Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in do_open(self, http_class, req, **http_conn_args)
1316 h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
1317 encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
1318 except OSError as err: # timeout erro
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas read\_csv from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32400867/pandas-read-csv-from-url) please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32400969/225020)

Comment: Which version of pandas are you using? The code you gave successfully loads the iris dataset for me with pandas version '0.23.4'.

Comment: Are you behind a corporate firewall or similar?

Comment: Hello, have the same problem, not the same errors... did you solve it?