# How to read CSV file from GitHub using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Im trying to read CSV file thats on github with Python using pandas> i have looked all over the web, and I tried some solution that I found on this website, but they do not work. What am I doing wrong?

I have tried this:

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://github.com/lukes/ISO-3166-Countries-with-Regional-Codes/blob/master/all/all.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(url,index_col=0)
#df = pd.read_csv(url)

print(df.head(5))
```

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32400867/pandas-read-csv-from-url - that might help you out!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You should provide URL to raw content. Try using this:

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lukes/ISO-3166-Countries-with-Regional-Codes/master/all/all.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(url, index_col=0)
print(df.head(5))
```

Output:

```
               alpha-2           ...            intermediate-region-code
name                             ...                                    
Afghanistan         AF           ...                                 NaN
Åland Islands       AX           ...                                 NaN
Albania             AL           ...                                 NaN
Algeria             DZ           ...                                 NaN
American Samoa      AS           ...                                 NaN
```

Comment: Or, you can simply add "?raw=true" at the end of the GitHub URL. You can see my answer below to view how the code looks.

Comment: Doing this using a gitlab public repo, I got an HTTPerror (`HTTP Error 403: Forbidden`). Is there a way to do the same with raw links on gitlab ?

Answer (score 29):

Add **?raw=true** at the end of the GitHub URL to get the raw file link.

In your case,

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://github.com/lukes/ISO-3166-Countries-with-Regional-Codes/blob/master/all/all.csv?raw=true'
df = pd.read_csv(url,index_col=0)
print(df.head(5))
```

Output:

```
               alpha-2 alpha-3  country-code     iso_3166-2   region  \
name                                                                   
Afghanistan         AF     AFG             4  ISO 3166-2:AF     Asia   
Åland Islands       AX     ALA           248  ISO 3166-2:AX   Europe   
Albania             AL     ALB             8  ISO 3166-2:AL   Europe   
Algeria             DZ     DZA            12  ISO 3166-2:DZ   Africa   
American Samoa      AS     ASM            16  ISO 3166-2:AS  Oceania   

                     sub-region intermediate-region  region-code  \
name                                                               
Afghanistan       Southern Asia                 NaN        142.0   
Åland Islands   Northern Europe                 NaN        150.0   
Albania         Southern Europe                 NaN        150.0   
Algeria         Northern Africa                 NaN          2.0   
American Samoa        Polynesia                 NaN          9.0   

                sub-region-code  intermediate-region-code  
name                                                       
Afghanistan                34.0                       NaN  
Åland Islands             154.0                       NaN  
Albania                    39.0                       NaN  
Algeria                    15.0                       NaN  
American Samoa             61.0                       NaN
```

**Note**: This works only with GitHub links and not with GitLab or Bitbucket links.

Comment: May I ask why when I read the file and print it, it only shows lines 0-20 then skips to 3000 and goes till the end. Note: there are 5000 lines.

Comment: @AirStalk3r You need to provide more information. May be post a new question with details.

Answer (score 6):

You can copy/paste the url and change 2 things:

1. Remove "blob"
2. Replace github.com by raw.githubusercontent.com

For instance this link:

```
https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data/blob/master/iris.csv
```

Works this way:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data/master/iris.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to either use pandas as you tried to and others here have explained, or depending on the application, the python csv-handler [CommaSeperatedPython](https://github.com/DapfiDuck/CommaSeperatedPython), which is a minimalistic wrapper for the native csv-library.

The library returns the contents of a file as a 2-Dimensional String-Array. It's is in its very early stage though, so if you want to do large scale data-analysis, I would suggest Pandas.

Answer (score 0):

First convert the github csv file to raw in order to access the data, follow the link below in comment on how to convert csv file to raw .

```
import pandas as pd

url_data = (r'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oderofrancis/rona/main/Countries-Continents.csv')

data_csv = pd.read_csv(url_data)

data_csv.head()
```

Comment: how to convert csv file to raw in github https://projectosyo.wixsite.com/datadoubleconfirm/single-post/2019/04/15/reading-csv-data-from-github-python