# How to upload csv file from GitHub to azure data lake using python script

Tags: azure-data-lake

I am new to cloud. I just want to understand how we will write script to get multiple csv files data from GitHub and upload them to data lake using python

Comment: Hi@VENKAT REDDY, Kindly let me know if you need more information. : )

Comment: Hi @VENKAT REDDY, If my answer is helpful for you, please accept(mark) it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Very thanks! : )

Answer (score 0):

I think you can read CSV files from GitHub using pandas, follow the example of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55240400/13979487). Then you can [upload blobs to a container](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python#upload-blobs-to-a-container) via the Python v12 SDK.