# Pandas read_csv from URL and include request header

Tags: python, pandas, http-headers, python-requests

As of Pandas 0.19.2, the function [read_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) can be passed a URL. See, for example, from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41880513/2327328):

```
import pandas as pd

url="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cs109/2014_data/master/countries.csv"
c=pd.read_csv(url)
```

---

The URL I'd like to use is: https://moz.com/top500/domains/csv

With the above code, this URL returns an error:

```
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13303449/2327328), I can get a valid response by passing a request header:

```
import urllib2,cookielib

site= "https://moz.com/top500/domains/csv"
hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11',
       'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
       'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
       'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
       'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
       'Connection': 'keep-alive'}

req = urllib2.Request(site, headers=hdr)

try:
    page = urllib2.urlopen(req)
except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
    print (e.fp.read())

content = page.read()
print (content)
```

Is there any way to use the web URL functionality of Pandas `read_csv()`, but also pass a request header to make the request go through?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of [pandas 1.3.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/whatsnew/v1.3.0.html), you can now pass custom HTTP(s) headers using `storage_options` argument:

```py
url = "https://moz.com:443/top500/domains/csv"

hdr = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive'
}

domains_df = pd.read_csv(url, storage_options=hdr)
```

Answer (score 15):

I would recommend you using the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) and the [io](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html) library for your task. The following code should do the job:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from io import StringIO

url = "https://moz.com:443/top500/domains/csv"
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0"}
req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
data = StringIO(req.text)

df = pd.read_csv(data)
print(df)
```

*(If you want to add a custom header just modify the `headers` variable)*

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks - I was not aware of the IO package previously. If possible, could you explain what the advantage of putting `req.text` into StringIO vs. reading the url directly with pandas like `df = pd.read_csv(url)` - actually I see you edited the question to reflect the new pandas version - do you believe that is the more efficient way?

Comment: @thesimplevoodoo Hey, the reason why I'm using StringIO here is that `pd.read_csv()` is expecting a filepath so giving it `url` or any other string including (`req.text`) would yield an error. By having `data = StringIO(req.text)` I can then use `data` as a file path (Do note that StringIO doesn't create any actual files but gives you the chance to  read and write strings as files)

Comment: This is a nice solution, though it should probably not be an accepted answer. It does not answer the OP's question: "Is there any way to use the web URL functionality of Pandas read_csv(), but also pass a request header to make the request go through?" I'm personally much more interested in the question as it pertained to `read_csv` and potential header usage.