# How to Read CSV from url in pandas? - error tokenizing data

Tags: python, pandas

How can I download this following file in python? I have no issue doing this in R. I believe this issue is the last row in the file which will change. How can I change the code to work?

```
import pandas as pd
 url = "https://ark-funds.com/wp-content/uploads/funds-etf-csv/ARK_INNOVATION_ETF_ARKK_HOLDINGS.csv"
test = pd.read_csv(url)
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: if you are getting 403 - forbidden error, then refer to this post [request with header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55711159/pandas-read-csv-from-url-and-include-request-header/55711425)

Answer (score 0):

You should better download the csv file first by using the [requests module](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/).
Then you can read the file from the download directory by passing the file path instead of the URL (*pd.read_csv(download_path)*).

Comment: `pd.read_csv()` supports reading from a URI.