# HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden when downloading csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, web-scraping, http-status-code-403

I have been stuck with this error for a few days. I went through a lot of related solutions, which are available on Stack Overflow and other websites, but still not getting a resolution.

I am using the below code for downloading data into CSV in Juyter Notebook - python (python 3, pandas version 1.0.5).

Referring to this video where the below code was working fine in video - 28.26 part of the video but I am getting error (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tW1BWtQRZ2M)

The initial "HTTPError" is provided at the bottom after all the errors provided below per link shared for duplicate.

I don't think this question should be a duplicate of [Pandas read_csv from URL and include request header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55711159/pandas-read-csv-from-url-and-include-request-header).

I tried using the code provided in the above link, but got below errors.

1. First code

   ```
   import pandas as pd
   import requests
   from io import StringIO

   url = "http://download.bls.gov/pub/time.series/cu/cu.item"

   headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0"}

   req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

   data = StringIO(req.text)

   df = pd.read_csv(data)

   print(df)

   import urllib2,cookielib

   site= "http://download.bls.gov/pub/time.series/cu/cu.item"
   hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11',
          'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
          'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
          'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
          'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
          'Connection': 'keep-alive'}

   req = urllib2.Request(site, headers=hdr)

   try:
       page = urllib2.urlopen(req)
   except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
       print (e.fp.read())

   content = page.read()
   print (content)

   url = "http://download.bls.gov/pub/time.series/cu/cu.item"

   hdr = {
       'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11',
       'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
       'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
       'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
       'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
       'Connection': 'keep-alive'
   }

   domains_df = pd.read_csv(url, storage_options=hdr)
   ```

   > ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line
   > 18, saw 2
2. Second code

   ```
   import urllib2,cookielib

   site= "http://download.bls.gov/pub/time.series/cu/cu.item"
   hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11',
          'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
          'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
          'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
          'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
          'Connection': 'keep-alive'}

   req = urllib2.Request(site, headers=hdr)

   try:
       page = urllib2.urlopen(req)
   except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
       print (e.fp.read())

   content = page.read()
   print (content)
   ```

   > SyntaxError: invalid syntax
3. Third code

   ```
   url = "http://download.bls.gov/pub/time.series/cu/cu.item"

   hdr = {
       'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11',
       'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
       'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
       'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
       'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
       'Connection': 'keep-alive'
   }

   domains_df = pd.read_csv(url, storage_options=hdr)
   ```

   > TypeError: parser_f() got an unexpected keyword argument 'storage_options'

URL to CSV - Initial HTTP error below

```
df=pd.read_csv('https://download.bls.gov/pub/time.series/cu/cu.item', sep= '\t')
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
HTTPError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-68e8ad1d75d5> in <module>
      1 ## URL to CSV
      2 
----> 3 df=pd.read_csv('https://download.bls.gov/pub/time.series/cu/cu.item', sep= '\t')
      4 ## the main thing is when you downalod from internet and open in notepad it will have slash t as separtor

~\Anan\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision)
    674         )
    675 
--> 676         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    677 
    678     parser_f.__name__ = name

~\Anan\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    428     # though mypy handling of conditional imports is difficult.
    429     # See https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/1297
--> 430     fp_or_buf, _, compression, should_close = get_filepath_or_buffer(
    431         filepath_or_buffer, encoding, compression
    432     )

~\Anan\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py in get_filepath_or_buffer(filepath_or_buffer, encoding, compression, mode)
    170 
    171     if isinstance(filepath_or_buffer, str) and is_url(filepath_or_buffer):
--> 172         req = urlopen(filepath_or_buffer)
    173         content_encoding = req.headers.get("Content-Encoding", None)
    174         if content_encoding == "gzip":

~\Anan\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py in urlopen(*args, **kwargs)
    139     import urllib.request
    140 
--> 141     return urllib.request.urlopen(*args, **kwargs)
    142 
    143 

~\Anan\lib\urllib\request.py in urlopen(url, data, timeout, cafile, capath, cadefault, context)
    220     else:
    221         opener = _opener
--> 222     return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
    223 
    224 def install_opener(opener):

~\Anan\lib\urllib\request.py in open(self, fullurl, data, timeout)
    529         for processor in self.process_response.get(protocol, []):
    530             meth = getattr(processor, meth_name)
--> 531             response = meth(req, response)
    532 
    533         return response

~\Anan\lib\urllib\request.py in http_response(self, request, response)
    638         # request was successfully received, understood, and accepted.
    639         if not (200 <= code < 300):
--> 640             response = self.parent.error(
    641                 'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
    642 

~\Anan\lib\urllib\request.py in error(self, proto, *args)
    567         if http_err:
    568             args = (dict, 'default', 'http_error_default') + orig_args
--> 569             return self._call_chain(*args)
    570 
    571 # XXX probably also want an abstract factory that knows when it makes

~\Anan\lib\urllib\request.py in _call_chain(self, chain, kind, meth_name, *args)
    500         for handler in handlers:
    501             func = getattr(handler, meth_name)
--> 502             result = func(*args)
    503             if result is not None:
    504                 return result

~\Anan\lib\urllib\request.py in http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs)
    647 class HTTPDefaultErrorHandler(BaseHandler):
    648     def http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs):
--> 649         raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    650 
    651 class HTTPRedirectHandler(BaseHandler):

HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Comment: 403 typically means that the server just doesn't **want** to talk to you.  Often this is because it thinks the request came from a robot, or because it doesn't like your ip address domain.

Comment: Were you using a proxy? Is that url directly accessible from your ip?

Comment: Basically a duplicate of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55711159/18470692). `requests` answer below already there. And you can also use the `storage_options` param inside `pd.read_csv`. Although I had to add `'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'` to the `header` to make it work. Not sure *why* that was needed, to be honest.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to download the file using `requests`:

```py
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

import requests

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/118.0",
}
url = "http://download.bls.gov/pub/time.series/cu/cu.item"
f = StringIO(requests.get(url, headers=headers).text)

df = pd.read_csv(f, sep="\t")
print(df.head())
```

Prints:

```
  item_code                                           item_name  display_level selectable  sort_sequence
0       AA0                                All items - old base              0          T              2
1      AA0R  Purchasing power of the consumer dollar - old base              0          T            400
2       SA0                                           All items              0          T              1
3      SA0E                                              Energy              1          T            375
4     SA0L1                                 All items less food              1          T            359
```