# I receive error when I want to read a URL containing a CSV file by pandas in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using pandas to read a CSV file through a URL in Python but I receive the following error:

> NameError: name 'pandas' is not defined

I have installed pandas in command prompt and was successful.
My code:

```
import pandas as pd
url = "https://community.watsonanalytics.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/WA_Fn-UseC_-Sales-Win-Loss.csv"
sales_data = pd.read_csv(url)
```

Comment: There is probably a problem with the installation. Did you install it using pip? Are you sure you have installed on the same python version you are using here?

Comment: Which editor are you using? Is it a virtual environment? The csv I dont think can be read directly from the url but that can be resolved after the pandas part. Try doing import pandas in the terminal

Comment: I installed it in command prompt and by the pip of the current version of python that I have installed on my computer, version of which is 3.7.3.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a duplicate. For earlier Pandas versions, this should work:

[Pandas read_csv from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32400867/pandas-read-csv-from-url)

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import io

url = "https://community.watsonanalytics.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/WA_Fn-UseC_-Sales-Win-Loss.csv"

s = requests.get(url).content
sales_data = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s.decode('utf-8')))
```

Comment: unfortunately even by your guidance I received this error.

Comment: Is it the same error? Edited so url is on one line. Try testing with a different url? What version of Python, Pandas are you using? This works on Pandas 0.24.2, Python 3.7.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.cameronvetter.com/nn-lab2/ has the link to access the data set.

```
https://www.cameronvetter.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/WA_Fn-UseC_-Sales-Win-Loss.csv
```