# download csv data through requests.get() retrieves me php text

Tags: python, csv, python-requests

I tried to download specific data as part of my work, 
the data is located in [link](https://estadisticas.bcrp.gob.pe/estadisticas/series/api/PN01210PM/csv/2015-01/2019-01)! .

The source indicates how to download through the get method, but when I make my requests:

```
    import requests
    import pandas as pd
    url="https://estadisticas.bcrp.gob.pe/estadisticas/series/api/PN01210PM/csv/2015-01/2019-01"
    r=pd.to_csv(url)
```

it doesnt read as it should be (open link in navigator).

When I try

```
    s=requests.get(url,verify=False) # you can set verify=True
    df=pd.DataFrame(s)
```

the data neither is good.

What else can I do? It suppose to download the data as csv avoiding me to clean the data.

Comment: You are probably looking for `pandas.read_csv()`. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32400867/pandas-read-csv-from-url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get the content as csv you can replace all HTML line breaks with newline chars.

please let me know if this works for you:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
url = "https://estadisticas.bcrp.gob.pe/estadisticas/series/api/PN01210PM/csv/2015-01/2019-01"
content = requests.get(url,verify=False).text.replace("<br>","\n").strip()
csv =  StringIO(content)
r = pd.read_csv(csv)

print(r)
```

Comment: it says `DataFrame constructor not properly called!`. if you replace `/csv/` for `/xls/` in url, it makes a download, Should not it be the same for csv?

Comment: please see my edit, I'm not using `DataFrame` constructor at all now