# To download a CSV file from a particular URL

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science

How do i download a CSV file from a url in Jupyter notebook? I know how to use wget command in Google colab platform but in case of Jupyter notebook what should i do?

Comment: Google Colab also provides you with a jupyter notebook. What is the actual problem you are facing. You can use `! wget <url>` to download the file

Answer (score 1):

If you have a direct link to the URL you can just enter the URL directly in pandas to get the file:

```
import pandas as pd
import io
import requests
url="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cs109/2014_data/master/countries.csv"
s=requests.get(url).content
c=pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s.decode('utf-8')))
```

Code is from this question: [Pandas read_csv from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32400867/pandas-read-csv-from-url)

Have a look at that as well maybe :)

Comment: you can read directly `pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cs109/2014_data/master/countries.csv")`. And you have it even in your link :)

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked. Actually i was having a problem in the last line as i was just using the read command on the csv. Can you explain the remaining part of the last line i.e. (io.StringIO(s.decode('utf-8')))

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("https://abc/xyz.csv")
```

For more, check the documentation:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```py
def download_csv_to_df(urllink):
    converted_dataframe = pd.read_csv(urllink)
    return converted_dataframe
```