# Downloading a Web File directly into Pandas

Tags: python, html, pandas, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to download a web file with this link in pandas. The issue that I am having is that most tutorials show a file that can be downloaded with a particular extension on the end, which allows for you to more easily directly download it.

This link results in the download of a text file, but it cannot be easily read with conventional methods. How can I download this file directly in pandas with [this link](https://www6.sos.state.oh.us/ords/f?p=VOTERFTP:DOWNLOAD::FILE:NO:2:P2_PRODUCT_NUMBER:1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data Science Acolyte, all you have to do is this!

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('ADAMS.txt')
```

you can try:

```
df = pd.read_csv('https://www6.sos.state.oh.us/ords/f?p=VOTERFTP:DOWNLOAD::FILE:NO:2:P2_PRODUCT_NUMBER:1')
```

Comment: It has to be with the link not with the downloaded file.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code below if it works for you:

```
import pandas as pd
import io
import requests

url="https://www6.sos.state.oh.us/ords/f?p=VOTERFTP:DOWNLOAD::FILE:NO:2:P2_PRODUCT_NUMBER:1"
s=requests.get(url).content
c=pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s.decode('utf-8')))
```

More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32400969/2131740).