# How to open csv file in pandas displaying all columns instead of entire data in only one column?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Firstly I've saved my file on my local disc with this code:

```
import requests
import csv

myDailyUrls = ['https://myurl.com/something//something_01-01-2020.csv', 'https://myurl.com/something//something_01-02-2020.csv']
for x in myDailyUrls:
    urldailyLocal= os.path.basename(x)
    response = requests.get(x, verify=False)        
    with open('/path/to/my/local/folder/'+urldailyLocal, 'w') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        for line in response.iter_lines():
            writer.writerow(line.decode('utf-8').split(','))
```

However, when I'm trying to open my previously saved file in pandas it opens data in dataframe including all columns data in only one column:

```
import pandas as pd
data = '/path/to/my/local/folder/oneOfMySavedFiles.csv'
lines = pd.read_csv(data, sep=',',header=3, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
```

What I realised is when I moved csv file manually to my local folder then the above pandas `pd.read_csv` would open it as expected with 8 columns, but when used one of the saved files for which I used `import csv` method then it will open all in 1 column.

Could someone help with this?

Comment: Have you checked that pandas is using the same encoding (utf-8)?

Comment: could you show `requests.get(...).content`?

Comment: Hi Dai, I've tried now with: `lines = pd.read_csv(data, sep=',',header=3, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, encoding='utf-8')` but same result. It shows for me `[39418 rows x 1 columns]`

Comment: Hi Danila, updated my question. Also, when I type 'response' it says: <Response [200]>

Comment: you can do it just using [StringIO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32400867/pandas-read-csv-from-url) + `df.to_csv()`.

Comment: Very helpful! thank you :)