# How do I make a GitHub into a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-lab

How do I import this [CSV file](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/doc/data/titanic.csv) into my JupyterLab DataFrame?

I want it to be transferred into a new DataFrame named Titanic I have done a Google search, as well as looked into the:
[Pandas.read_csv() function?](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv) I know that JupyterLab has a `read_csv` function that might solve the problem.

I did try:

```py
import "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pandas-dev/pandas/master/doc/data/titanic.csv" as Titanic
```

But that raised an error:

```
File "<ipython-input-1-67adbf7f2871>", line 2
    import "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pandas-dev/pandas/master/doc/data/titanic.csv" as Titanic

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Could you format your question such that it is readable and has a clear explanation of what you want and what you have tried already? See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: you misunderstand what you are trying to do. look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41880513/7540911) answer, it's what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
import pandas as pd

dataset = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pandas-dev/pandas/master/doc/data/titanic.csv", sep=",")
```

which gives:

```
PassengerId  Survived  Pclass  \
0              1         0       3   
1              2         1       1   
2              3         1       3   
3              4         1       1   
4              5         0       3   
..           ...       ...     ...   
886          887         0       2   
887          888         1       1   
888          889         0       3   
889          890         1       1   
890          891         0       3   

                                                  Name     Sex   Age  SibSp  \
0                              Braund, Mr. Owen Harris    male  22.0      1   
1    Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Th...  female  38.0      1   
2                               Heikkinen, Miss. Laina  female  26.0      0   
3         Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)  female  35.0      1   
4                             Allen, Mr. William Henry    male  35.0      0   
..                                                 ...     ...   ...    ...   
886                              Montvila, Rev. Juozas    male  27.0      0   
887                       Graham, Miss. Margaret Edith  female  19.0      0   
888           Johnston, Miss. Catherine Helen "Carrie"  female   NaN      1   
889                              Behr, Mr. Karl Howell    male  26.0      0   
890                                Dooley, Mr. Patrick    male  32.0      0   

     Parch            Ticket     Fare Cabin Embarked  
0        0         A/5 21171   7.2500   NaN        S  
1        0          PC 17599  71.2833   C85        C  
2        0  STON/O2. 3101282   7.9250   NaN        S  
3        0            113803  53.1000  C123        S  
4        0            373450   8.0500   NaN        S  
..     ...               ...      ...   ...      ...  
886      0            211536  13.0000   NaN        S  
887      0            112053  30.0000   B42        S  
888      2        W./C. 6607  23.4500   NaN        S  
889      0            111369  30.0000  C148        C  
890      0            370376   7.7500   NaN        Q  

[891 rows x 12 columns]
```