# How to read a csv file from url using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, python-requests

I would like to load a csv into a pandas dataframe and the data is available on a remote server.

The goal is to read it directly to a dataframe without writing the data to disk.

`url = https://dev.azure.com/tankerkoenig/tankerkoenig-data/_git/tankerkoenig-data?path=/prices/2022/07/2022-07-01-prices.csv`

I am thinking about an approach like this:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

r = requests.get(url)
df = pd.read_csv(r.content)
```

Does anyone know if something like this is possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32400867/pandas-read-csv-from-url

Comment: Unfortunately the solution only works for files on github not for tankerkoenig.

Comment: No, it is available for everyone. You can also can access these fuel prices.

Answer (score 1):

You can call `read_csv` method directly.

```
import pandas as pd

url="https://dev.azure.com/tankerkoenig/tankerkoenig-data/_git/tankerkoenig-data?path=/prices/2022/07/2022-07-01-prices.csv"
df=pd.read_csv(url)
```

OR if you want the text in string and read

```
from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd
import requests
url='https://dev.azure.com/tankerkoenig/tankerkoenig-data/_git/tankerkoenig-data?path=/prices/2022/07/2022-07-01-prices.csv'
s=requests.get(url).text

df=pd.read_csv(StringIO(s))
```

Comment: Solution 1: I am receiving an error called ```ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 8, saw 2```

Solution 2: Getting an error called ```AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'```

Comment: @Daniel, can you try now?

Comment: When trying out solution 2 I am receiving the same error when executing solution 1. It seems the data is received but the schema cannot be read properly.

Comment: Ok, then if you can receive the data, the issue is not with authentication. What fields do you need from this data?

Comment: date, station_uuid, diesel, e5, e10, dieselchange, e5change and e10change.

Comment: Ok, so all fields. I suspect date is causing some issue. Let me check

Comment: When using ```sep='delimiter'```I can see that only html data is received...

Comment: I got connection refused error. So I suspect it is something with the URL. I checked the data and it seems to be ok. So issue si with getting the data. Is it possible to download he file locally and then process?  raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='dev.azure.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /tankerkoenig/tankerkoenig-data/_git/tankerkoenig-data?path=/prices/2022/07/2022-07-01-prices.csv (

Comment: I think you receiving html data is proof that csv is not accessible.