# error when I'm using a URL from a GitHub user dataset to use in python

Tags: python, pandas, read.csv

*Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 28, saw 367*

I keep getting an error when I'm using a URL from a GitHub user dataset to use in python to run. Is there a way to solve this issue?

```
url = "https://github.com/noghte/datasets/blob/main/apartments.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(url)
print(len(df, index_col=0))
```

```
Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text editor
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ParserError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~/8410_Projects/Lessons/week9.DataFrame.py in <module>
      4 # https://raw.githubusercontent.com/noghte/datasets/mainapartment.csv
      5 url = "https://github.com/noghte/datasets/blob/main/apartments.csv"
----> 6 df = pd.read_csv(url)
      7 print(len(df, index_col=0))

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    309                     stacklevel=stacklevel,
    310                 )
--> 311             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    312 
    313         return wrapper

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py in read_csv(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, encoding_errors, dialect, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, on_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision, storage_options)
    584     kwds.update(kwds_defaults)
    585 
--> 586     return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    587 
    588 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    486 
    487     with parser:
...

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas read\_csv from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32400867/pandas-read-csv-from-url)

Comment: As per the duplicate, try: `url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/noghte/datasets/main/apartments.csv"`. This url is accessible by clicking "View Raw" on the page of your original url. When you hover over it, you'll find that it actually fires https://github.com/noghte/datasets/blob/main/apartments.csv?raw=True. So, you could in fact also just load the url *with* that query included (i.e. adding "?raw=True"). Incidentally, `print(len(df, index_col=0))` is not a valid statement, since `len()` does not take keyword arguments (and `index_col=0` would be one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is another alternative way of loading csv from url. Try it this way too to see if the error persists:

```
import pandas as pd
import io
import requests
url="https://github.com/noghte/datasets/blob/main/apartments.csv"
s=requests.get(url).content
c=pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s.decode('utf-8')))
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas is attempting to read the entire page rather than just the raw csv file like you want.
Add a raw query to your URL like so:

```
url = "https://github.com/noghte/datasets/blob/main/apartments.csv*?raw=true*"
```