# How to manage an API with Python that downloads a compressed folder?

Tags: python, api, request

I am trying to use an API that downloads a compressed folder containing different images. How can I use this Request url in Python to download the folder and choose the path in which I would like this folder to register ?

Request url :

https://monitoring.greisch.com/api/dashboard/zipDashboard/298d5df9-4754-4f70-a228-e24a1bf6ac77/2019-08-18/2019-09-17/hour

I tried this :

```py
import urllib.request

url = 'https://monitoring.greisch.com/api/dashboard/zipDashboard/298d5df9-4754-4f70-a228-e24a1bf6ac77/2019-08-18/2019-09-17/hour'

path ='R:/my/path/'
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, path + 'Dashboard.zip')
print('file downloaded')
```

But I get this error message :

```
raceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1317, in do_open
    encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\http\client.py", line 1229, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\http\client.py", line 1275, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\http\client.py", line 1224, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\http\client.py", line 1016, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\http\client.py", line 956, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\http\client.py", line 1384, in connect
    super().connect()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\http\client.py", line 928, in connect
    (self.host,self.port), self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\socket.py", line 727, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\socket.py", line 716, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] Aucune connexion n’a pu être établie car l’ordinateur cible l’a expressément refusée
```

But if I access the URL via a web browser, it works and the download of the compressed folder is automatically launched.

EDIT :

The solution was :

```
    url = 'http://url.com/apirequest/'
    wget.download(url, '/path/to/destination/folder/' + filename)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download file from web in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7243750/download-file-from-web-in-python-3)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass credentials to your request. `r=requests.get(url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username, password))` Answer based on [Getting a file from an authenticated site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24835100/getting-a-file-from-an-authenticated-site-with-python-urllib-urllib2)