# How do I download a file with authorization - python

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib, wget

I have the link of a file that directly downloads an Excel file, the link requests authorization (user name, password), I need Python to enter with the login data and download the file

```
url = 'https://url.com/format=xlsx
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to "log in" to a website using Python's Requests module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11892729/how-to-log-in-to-a-website-using-pythons-requests-module)

Comment: you can easly find the answer to your question just using the search tool of stackoverflow =)
For example [using urllib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/395451/how-to-download-a-file-over-http-with-authorization-in-python-3-0-working-aroun) or [using requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45107839/python-login-and-download-specific-file-from-website)